# Crystal reports me pide iniciar sesión en SQL para generar un informe C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Buen día, tengo un problema con crystal reports, he generado un reporte y en la maquina donde estoy desarrollando si lo genera sin problemas, el problema es al pasar al equipo cliente (otro equipo) cada ves que se generará el reporte me pide iniciar sesión del SQL, estoy trabajando con windows forms, SQL 2008 R2. (Es una base de datos en red)
Quisiera que dejara de aparecer la ventana de inicio de sesión SQL, ya he probado muchas formas y simplemente no funciona...
Dejo captura de lo que me sale en los equipos cliente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Luego de cargar su reporte, coloque esta linea: `rpt_documento.SetDatabaseLogon("******", "******");` especifique ahi su usuario y clave!

Comment: Ya lo hice, por eso aparece el usuario y la clave, pero me he fijado que el campo donde dice base de datos: está en blanco y deshabilitado lo tengo conectado por datasource de mi proyecto.

Comment: Yo tuve el mismo problema y nunca logré solucionarlo, terminé migrando a Reportviewer, los datos que pide no son los del SQLServer sino los de los odbc a los que se conectan, el tema es que parece que en ciertas circunstancias el driver de odbc es un poco conflictivo con ese tema.. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde codigo tienes que indicar la info de conexion a la db si es que este lo conectas directo a la db.

[Agregar el código de conexión del informe](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms227471(v=vs.90))

en el codigo observaras como se asigna la info de conexion al objeto `ConnectionInfo`

```
TableLogOnInfos tableLogOnInfos = crystalReportViewer.LogOnInfo;

ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "Northwind";
connectionInfo.UserID = "limitedPermissionAccount";
connectionInfo.Password = "1234";

foreach(TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo in tableLogOnInfos)
{
   tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
}
```

Una opcion que recomendaria utilizar hace uso de `dataset tipados` como origen de datos del reporte, de esta forma el reporte nunca se conectara a la db directamente sino que desde codigo debes cargar el `dataset` que asignarias como report source.

Comment: No me ha funcionado, mi consulta está en un procedimiento almacenado no se si eso tenga que ver...

Comment: pero si pones un breakpoint y analizas las TableLogOnInfos  puedes ver que ConnectionInfo  tiene asignada? porque basicamente eso es lo que debes definir

Comment: Opté por hacerlo en reportviewer ya que no pude lograrlo con el crystal... Gracias de todos modos! Saludos! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo resolví de la siguiente manera: al final solo le le dí click  sobre el objeto CrystalReportViewer (en la flechita para ver las configuraciones) ahí hay que quitarle el check que dice:

Enable Database Logon Prompting

tal como lo muestro en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, para la próxima ya sabré jaja batalle tanto y no vi esa simple config! :(